# Could my recent UK visit affect my spouse visa application?

Tags: united-kingdom

I applied for 32-day visit visa for the UK and was given six months to visit my wife's family. Upon arriving in UK, my wife got depressed due to a family loss and was put on anti-depressants by her GP and counsellor. From this reason, I had to extend my stay to five months to help her with her recovery before heading back home.

It did not cross my mind to inform Immigration of the change. I left after five months. My wife is still on anti-depressants in the UK and I want to join her so 
I plan to apply for a spouse visa.

Will the earlier length of visit affect my new application for a spouse visa?

Comment: Where are you from? You mean you requested a visa for 32 days and they gave you one for six months, then you stayed for five months, is that correct?

Comment: Yes correct! And I am from Kenya

Comment: The six month limit is a standard period, issued to everyone under normal circumstances - regardless of the reasons for the extended stay, it shows that your ties to your country of residence is not as strong as your application suggests (who can suddenly extend a stay by 4 months without suffering job and financial issues?) and your credibility may be strained on your next application as a result.

Comment: My wife was sick and it was not my intentions to extend my stay that long. And as for work I was given 4 months unpaid leave to look after my wife,I know I suffered financially from but I had other sources of income from my country that I had included in the application. Anyways thanks for your response it really helped

Comment: @GayotFow the main point was to seek advice on my extension due to the reason I gave for future applications to the UK. Like I said the spouse visa was something for the future I don't see how that does not make sense and it has to be off-topic?

Comment: If the question is voted on-topic, I'll give an answer that addresses spouse visas explicitly. The other answers here assume that you want to be a visitor and do not work for spouse applicants.

Comment: @GayotFow thank you very. I will check the site and once again thank you so much I appreciate your input!

Comment: @Hassan you can read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers in the meantime along with http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

> Could my recent UK visit affect my spouse visa application?

Yes, it will. You said you would stay 32 days and actually stayed five months, so your credibility is damaged. However that alone would not necessarily prevent you obtaining a visa (planning ahead always involves some uncertainty). You should explain the reasons and support these with appropriate documentation, such as a letter from her GP.

As explained in [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/79989/4995) you may also have some explaining to do about your finances.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try and see if we could get a letter from her GP but would a letter also from her counsellor help?

Comment: Letter from GP was just an example. That should confirm the depression. A letter from a Counsellor might help to confirm your contribution/the value to her condition of your staying on.

Comment: @Gayot Might you elaborate on that? I'm not sure whether you are suggesting no evidence will make any difference, or some other evidence might. My view was that a GP's letter would serve at least to confirm the depression was not pure fabrication.

Comment: @Gayot Presumably not, but Counsellor might have, in so far as able to 'prescribe' anything.

Comment: @pnuts those prescriptions arent worth anything - a counsellor is not a medical professional and their recommendations don't carry any legal weight.  The issue here is that depression is not something that can artificially extend a stay unexpectedly - the husband could have returned home, and the wife could have gone with him.  Beyond the self imposed obligation to stay and support his wife, nothing about the wifes medical situation would *require* him to stay in the UK - mitigating evidence here may be hard to come by.

Comment: @pnuts I'm not down voting, but it looks like your answer has been hastily  culled from previous answers already on the site and contains the afterthought that a GP's letter will be helpful to the OP. I don't see that happening.

Comment: @Moo IMO "legal weight" is not required. I agree *mitigating evidence here may be hard to come by* but what I wrote was *You should explain the reasons and support these with appropriate documentation*. Are you suggesting it would be detrimental to attempt any explanation, or better  explain but support that in some other (what?) way?

Comment: @Gayot If my answer is the same as elsewhere here I'd guess so is the Q. Should that be closed as a dupe (of which?) ?

Comment: @pnuts at this point it might be worthwhile to go back and copy more info to give your answer some weight http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79986/uk-visa-refusal-on-credibility-grounds-longer-visit-than-originally-described/79989#79989

Comment: @pnuts the issue is that counselors are not regulated in the UK, and thus any documentation from his wifes counselor is worth no more than a letter from his wife would be.  I am saying that, along the same lines as many types of financial documentation some people present, a letter from a counselor in the UK runs a very real risk of being dismissed out of hand.  A letter from a doctor carries actual legal weight as the opinion of a legally regulated practitioner.

Comment: @pnuts for example, in the UK a counselor cannot certify any absence forms for your employer, only your doctor can do that.  This would be much the same situation legally.

Comment: @MooThe situation at which my wife was at with her depression she could not leave the country because her GP had to monitor her and she could not be given more than a month's worth of anti-depressants because her GP was worried she might commit suicide . In Kenya medical expenses are very expensive and as its not as best as the rest of the world.I could leave at the end of 32 days but her counsellor saw that my presence was helping with her health,she needed me there It might not make sense but I just need some advice and a way forward to help me in the future even though this has happend

Comment: @Moo so would a letter from the GP carry any weight on this matter?

Comment: @Hassan I am sympathetic with your situation, but we are trying to establish some grounds for staying longer than planned, which means some difficult discussion on the topic.  Regardless of what your wife was prescribed by her doctor or recommended by her counselor, neither of those form a firm basis for an extended stay on your behalf - marital support is all well and good, but does it form a good basis for a compassionate explanation here that overrides the damage to your credibility in this case...  do you see the issue?

Comment: @Hassan in your case - no.  My wife is a GP and is giving me advice as I type this - she would not get involved in your application in any way at all.  There may be scope for you going to a private GP and requesting some form of letter, but NHS GP's will almost certainly refuse you out of hand at such a request.

Comment: @GayotFow Im not sure this is health tourism, as I get the impression that the wife has leave to remain or is a UK citizen already, rather than accompanying him on the visit - I could be wrong but... otherwise, why the application for a spousal visa?

Comment: @Moo Why "override"? OP surely knows there is risk and surely we (me at least) are not trying to guarantee success (that's not possible) - merely seeking to mitigate the damage. To repeat OP's Comment **so would a letter from the GP carry any weight on this matter?** If you think it would make matters worse (as Gayot seems to) then a downvote here would seem in order.

Comment: @pnuts to answer the GP letter question - no, it would not help.  No GP is going to write a letter that will be helpful in this situation.

Comment: @pnuts by override, I specifically mean that establishing that the compassionate terms of the extended stay sets aside the damage to credibility aspect, but that would be easier to demonstrate if the wife had a terminal illness etc rather than depression (she does have family around her in the UK, so her husbands presence is not *required*).

Comment: @I totally understand you and thanks for the advice!

Comment: @GayotFow about the spouse,that was just a plan for the future

Comment: @Moo No GP is going to write something along the lines "I have been treating Mrs Hassan for depression since July 2016" or writing something like that would not help? I'm still not clear whether your point is "no chance of any letter" (I'd dispute that!) or "no letter of any kind would help".

Comment: @pnuts writing something like that wont help, as it establishes no grounds for an extended stay.  The GP would have to add weight to the husbands presence being extremely beneficial or a requirement, and they won't do that.  My wife has said that she simply wouldnt write a letter intended for use as supporting evidence in a visa application in this situation, regardless of what it said - just describing the diagnosis and treatment wouldn't be of any value so its not worth it to her professional exposure.

Comment: @pnuts put it this way - if he wasnt already in the country, would her illness constitute compassionate grounds for granting a visa with no other supporting evidence?  If not, then why would it support grounds for an unplanned extended stay where there is no other supporting evidence?

Comment: @Moo It would seem to be better grounds than no other grounds (even if still not *enough* grounds).

Comment: @pnuts ... in the same vein as homeopathy is better medicine than no other medicine...? ;)

Comment: So you are all saying I will no longer be granted entry into the UK in the future?

Comment: @Hassan I'm not taking a view on that, merely trying to improve your chances. Nobody can be certain (other than the ECO/IO) but it seems Moo thinks you will not be and probably Gayot also - and bear in mind that Gayot is an expert and I am not. What perhaps we do agree on is that to *Will the earlier length of visit affect my new application for a spouse visa?* the answer is "Yes, probably."

Comment: @Hassan I am saying that its doubtful your wifes situation constitutes strong enough grounds for the additional 4 months of stay on its own to mitigate the damage to subsequent applications credibility.  You will need a *lot* more, including showing how it did not constitute a weak link with your home country, job etc.  How could you manage to drop everything in your home country without damaging those links etc etc.

Comment: @Moo Now you seem to agree with everything I wrote except "such as a letter from her GP"?

Comment: @pnuts I have always agreed with everything other than the letter from GP aspect.  Mitigating circumstances will be difficult to prove here, as the GP won't provide anything which will support a visa application for a third party, and the counselors have no standing with which any documentation they provide would have any weight.

Comment: @Moo *just describing the diagnosis and treatment wouldn't be of any value* according to whom? My view (and it *is* only a personal opinion) is that (almost any) *evidence* that the wife was suffering from depression would help a claim by the husband that his wife was suffering depression (regardless of whether such a claim makes any difference to a visa application).

Comment: @Moo,Pnuts and GayotFow thank you guys for your inputs you have all helped me a lot! Thank you all and God bless

Comment: @pnuts if you want to come to chat I can explain the reasoning to you

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52809/could-my-recent-uk-visit-affect-my-spouse-visa-application

Comment: Guys feel free to tell me anything that might help or NOT help,just throw it all at me

Answer (score 1):

You were on a visit visa to the UK and stayed for much longer than you had told them you would. You contemplate a spouse visa now.

> Will the earlier length of visit affect my new application for a
>   spouse visa?

No. Not at all. Here's why...

A visit visa takes place under Appendix V of the rules and a spouse visa takes place under Paragraph 281/282 of the rules.  Different rules, different topology, different assumptions, **and different ECO's**!

Even *overstaying* on a visit visa doesn't affect a spouse visa. There's an explicit carve out in Part 9 of the rules.

There is no reason why staying for a long time would counter-indicate your intention to settle in the UK. That's what settlement means right? You plan to live here permanently.

Worry about something else.